# Proving a subset is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ & Writing basis/dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help showing that

$W = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    3s - 2t \\
    s + 2t \\  
    2s + 3t \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$ such that $s$ and $t$ are real numbers is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I also need to write a basis of $W$ and state the dimension of $W$.

My ideas:

I know that the conditions for a subset being a subspace is that it most include the zero vector, and be closed under addition and multiplication. However, I do not know how to do this.

I am not so sure about writing a basis of $W$, or stating the dimension of $W$, either.

Comment: You are describing the set of all vectors of the form $s\left[ \begin{matrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{matrix} \right] + t\left[ \begin{matrix} -2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{matrix} \right]$, or all linear combinations of the vectors $\mathbf{u} := \left[ \begin{matrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{matrix} \right]$ and $\mathbf{v} := \left[ \begin{matrix} -2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{matrix} \right]$. In other words, $\mathsf{span} \left(\left[ \begin{matrix} 3 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{matrix} \right], \left[ \begin{matrix} -2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{matrix} \right]\right)$.

Comment: latex error i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to write the subset as:
$$W=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
    3s - 2t \\
    s + 2t \\  
    2s + 3t \\ 
\end{bmatrix}:s,t \in \mathbb{R}\right\}.$$

> I know that the conditions for a subset being a subspace is that it most include the zero vector, and be closed under addition and multiplication. However, I do not know how to do this.

- To show the zero vector belongs to the set, we find values of $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
  $$\begin{bmatrix}
      3s - 2t \\
      s + 2t \\  
      2s + 3t \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
      0 \\
      0 \\  
      0 \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}.$$
- To show that it's closed under addition, we take two arbitrary elements from $W$, add them together, and show that the result is in $W$.  I.e. show
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}
      3s - 2t \\
      s + 2t \\  
      2s + 3t \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  +
  \begin{bmatrix}
      3s' - 2t' \\
      s' + 2t' \\  
      2s' + 3t' \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
      3(s+s') - 2(t+t') \\
      (s+s') + 2(t+t') \\  
      2(s+s') + 3(t+t') \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$
  belongs to $W$.
- To show that it's closed under scalar multiplication, we take an arbitrary element from $W$, and multiply it by an arbitrary scalar $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and show that the result is in $W$.  I.e., we show
  $$
  \alpha
  \begin{bmatrix}
      3s - 2t \\
      s + 2t \\  
      2s + 3t \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
      3\alpha s - 2\alpha t \\
      \alpha s + 2\alpha t \\  
      2\alpha s + 3\alpha t \\ 
  \end{bmatrix}
  $$
  is in $W$.

To identify a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) (a spanning, linearly independent subset), the co-efficients of $s$ and the coefficients of $t$ should give hint.  We can rewrite $W$ as:
$$W=\left\{s\begin{bmatrix}
    3 \\
    1 \\  
    2 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}
    - 2 \\
    2 \\  
    3 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}:s,t \in \mathbb{R}\right\}.$$  Note: we need to check that the basis vectors are indeed linearly independent.

The dimension of $W$ is the size of any of it's bases, by the [Dimension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces), so once you've found a basis, the answer to this part is "what's it's size?".